# Should static text be stored in a .properties file?

Tags: java, jsp, properties

Given a .JSP, would there be any reason to store static text in a .properties file, pull the key/value pair, and display it? Is that the best practice / standardized way? If so, why? Or can you "hard code" the static text into the .JSP? Are there benefits (performance, code readability, etc.) with each way?

Comment: If you place it in a file, or any DB for that matter, you can make changes to that text without having to have a code release. It really depends on what your needs are for the maintenance of the app.

Comment: To me, it's all about maintenance.  Storing it in a DB or whatever simplifies maintenance.

Comment: for multi lingual application, this is one of the approach, you just separate that text in to property file or anywhere , so that you need not to change any code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on what the "text" is. If it's user-visible, such as form labels, then storing it in a properties file allows you to make use of the built-in i18n capabilities of JSP and similar technologies, and it also permits easy updates in case of typos or such. Externalizing user-visible text is always a good best practice.

If the text is something that's "static" but likely to change on a reasonably frequent basis, then it belongs in a persistent store such as the database you're using for your other persistence, or a document database like MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

My response could differ depending on what you are referring to as static text?  Storing the values within a properties file is one way of approaching it, but I would advise that you store these types of key value pairs in a database that you could later retrieve and cache at start-up.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can store your text in the database. I think this is most preferrable way.